# RapidJSON : Differences between building using Document or Writer

Tags: c++, json, rapidjson

I want to use `rapidJSON` to build JSON files.
I've noticed there are (at least) 2 options to do so.
The first is using `rapidJSON::Writer` directly :

```
StringBuffer s;
Writer<StringBuffer> writer(s);
writer.StartObject();
writer.String("hello");
...
```

The other is using `rapidJSON::Document` :

```
Document d;
d.SetObject();
d.AddMember("hello", "world", d.GetAllocator());
...
```

Besides the obvious differences of ease of use on the `Document` side and more type control on the `Writer` size,  are there any performance differences ? are both allocations the same ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Document` is a data structure for storing JSON tree (aka DOM) in memory. `Writer` is needed to stringify (dump/serialize) a `Document` into JSON:

```
d.Accept(writer);
```

So, if your application only needs to write JSON, and it can apply `Writer` easily, it is preferred over `Document`. It is because `Document` needs memory allocation and additional overheads.

However, `Document` is more easily for parsing and modify JSON.

P.S. In the current version of RapidJSON, it is prefer to use `writer.Key("hello")` instead of `writer.String("hello")` for object keys.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried using the `Writer` but I wasn't able to find a way to add 'array of objects' using `Writer`, using the `Document` it was easily done, is there a way of doing so using `Writer` ? Thanks

Comment: You can actually uses MyHandler in http://miloyip.github.io/rapidjson/md_doc_sax.html to dump the DOM, just d.Accept(MyHandler())